# Is it possible to select multiple overlapping date ranges with a single query using mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, date-range

I currently have a somewhat large SQL statement that UNIONs the same SELECT statement 3 times each time with a larger date range. IE Last 30 days, Last 90 Days and Last 180 Days. The SQL works just fine and I am even OK with the fact that the query takes quite a while to run, I am just wondering if there is anyway to do the same thing with just one SELECT statement.

Seeing as a couple of people asked to see my code:-

```
SELECT mdt_userid AS logging_officer,
    'Last 30 Days' AS timespan,
    ACD_Time,
    TRUNCATE (( 1 - ( (TotalAssisting+TotalBRB+TotalShift+TotalLunch+TotalBreak-IF(TotalLunch<(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch),TotalLunch,(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch))-IF((TotalBRB+TotalBreak)<(DaysLoggedIn*1800),(TotalBRB+TotalBreak),(DaysLoggedIn*1800))) / (TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) ) ) *100,2) AS Utilization_percent,
    TRUNCATE((GRS_total/calls)*100,1) AS Ratio,
    IF (TotalACW =0,0,TotalACW / calls) AS ACW,
    grs.percent AS percent,
    TRUNCATE (((grs_total - wo_ci) / grs_total) *100,2) AS percent_w_ci,
    TRUNCATE (calls / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS call_per_hour,
    TRUNCATE (GRS_total / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS grs_per_hour 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fullname,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '138',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalAssisting,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '146',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBRB,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '143',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalShift,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '141',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalACW,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '231',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalEreq,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '0',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalDefault,
            COUNT(ReasonCode = '136') AS CountLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '136',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '137',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBreak,
            SUM(  `ReasonCodeDuration` ) AS NRduration
        FROM  `CiscoAgentNotready` 
        WHERE StartDate >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-30)." 00:00:00' 
                AND StartDate <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY fullname)
        AS notready, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT agentname,
            SUM( loginduration ) AS TotalLoginTime, COUNT(Date(logondate)) as DaysLoggedIn
        FROM CiscoAgentLogintime
        WHERE logondate  >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-30)." 00:00:00' 
                AND logondate  <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY agentname)
        AS logintime, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT full_name, 
            SUM( handled ) AS calls
        FROM  `CiscoAgentCalls` 
        WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-30)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."'
        GROUP BY full_name)
        AS calls, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT logging_officer, 
            SUM( first_call ) AS firstcall, 
            SUM(IF (Config_item =  'unknown', 1, 0) ) AS wo_ci,
            COUNT( * ) AS GRS_total, 
            TRUNCATE ((SUM( first_call ) / COUNT( * )) *100,2) AS percent
        FROM (SELECT logging_officer, 
                IF (logging_officer =  `Resolving_Officer` , 1, 0) AS first_call, 
                Config_item
            FROM  `callcentergrsdata` 
            WHERE log_Date >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-30)." 00:00:00' 
                 AND log_Date <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59') 
            AS a
        GROUP BY logging_officer) 
        AS grs,
    (SELECT DISTINCT agtName,
            SUM(TalkTime) as sumTalk,
            SUM(CallsHandled) as answered,
            SUM(TalkTime)/SUM(CallsHandled) as ACD_Time
        FROM (SELECT CONCAT( LastName,  ', ', FirstName ) AS agtName,
                TalkTime, 
                CallsHandled
            FROM `CiscoAgentAHT`
            WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-30)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."') as subAHT
        GROUP BY agtName) 
        AS AHT,
    techjtblnew
WHERE mdt_userid = '".$user."'
AND notready.fullname = logintime.agentname
AND calls.full_name = notready.fullname 
AND calls.full_name = AHT.agtName
AND techjtblnew.cisco = notready.fullname 
AND grs.logging_officer = techjtblnew.grs
UNION 
SELECT mdt_userid AS logging_officer,
    'Last 90 Days' AS timespan,
    ACD_Time,
    TRUNCATE (( 1 - ( (TotalAssisting+TotalBRB+TotalShift+TotalLunch+TotalBreak-IF(TotalLunch<(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch),TotalLunch,(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch))-IF((TotalBRB+TotalBreak)<(DaysLoggedIn*1800),(TotalBRB+TotalBreak),(DaysLoggedIn*1800))) / (TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) ) ) *100,2) AS Utilization_percent,
    TRUNCATE((GRS_total/calls)*100,1) AS Ratio,
    IF (TotalACW =0,0,TotalACW / calls) AS ACW,
    grs.percent AS percent,
    TRUNCATE (((grs_total - wo_ci) / grs_total) *100,2) AS percent_w_ci,
    TRUNCATE (calls / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS call_per_hour,
    TRUNCATE (GRS_total / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS grs_per_hour 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fullname,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '138',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalAssisting,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '146',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBRB,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '143',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalShift,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '141',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalACW,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '231',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalEreq,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '0',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalDefault,
            COUNT(ReasonCode = '136') AS CountLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '136',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '137',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBreak,
            SUM(  `ReasonCodeDuration` ) AS NRduration
        FROM  `CiscoAgentNotready` 
        WHERE StartDate >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-90)." 00:00:00' 
                AND StartDate <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY fullname)
        AS notready, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT agentname,
            SUM( loginduration ) AS TotalLoginTime, COUNT(Date(logondate)) as DaysLoggedIn
        FROM CiscoAgentLogintime
        WHERE logondate  >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-90)." 00:00:00' 
                AND logondate  <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY agentname)
        AS logintime, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT full_name, 
            SUM( handled ) AS calls
        FROM  `CiscoAgentCalls` 
        WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-90)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."'
        GROUP BY full_name)
        AS calls, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT logging_officer, 
            SUM( first_call ) AS firstcall, 
            SUM(IF (Config_item =  'unknown', 1, 0) ) AS wo_ci,
            COUNT( * ) AS GRS_total, 
            TRUNCATE ((SUM( first_call ) / COUNT( * )) *100,2) AS percent
        FROM (SELECT logging_officer, 
                IF (logging_officer =  `Resolving_Officer` , 1, 0) AS first_call, 
                Config_item
            FROM  `callcentergrsdata` 
            WHERE log_Date >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-90)." 00:00:00' 
                 AND log_Date <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59') 
            AS a
        GROUP BY logging_officer) 
        AS grs,
    (SELECT DISTINCT agtName,
            SUM(TalkTime) as sumTalk,
            SUM(CallsHandled) as answered,
            SUM(TalkTime)/SUM(CallsHandled) as ACD_Time
        FROM (SELECT CONCAT( LastName,  ', ', FirstName ) AS agtName,
                TalkTime, 
                CallsHandled
            FROM `CiscoAgentAHT`
            WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-90)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."') as subAHT
        GROUP BY agtName) 
        AS AHT,
    techjtblnew
WHERE mdt_userid = '".$user."'
AND notready.fullname = logintime.agentname
AND calls.full_name = notready.fullname 
AND calls.full_name = AHT.agtName
AND techjtblnew.cisco = notready.fullname 
AND grs.logging_officer = techjtblnew.grs
UNION 
SELECT mdt_userid AS logging_officer,
    'Last 120 Days' AS timespan,
    ACD_Time,
    TRUNCATE (( 1 - ( (TotalAssisting+TotalBRB+TotalShift+TotalLunch+TotalBreak-IF(TotalLunch<(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch),TotalLunch,(DaysLoggedIn*Lunch))-IF((TotalBRB+TotalBreak)<(DaysLoggedIn*1800),(TotalBRB+TotalBreak),(DaysLoggedIn*1800))) / (TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) ) ) *100,2) AS Utilization_percent,
    TRUNCATE((GRS_total/calls)*100,1) AS Ratio,
    IF (TotalACW =0,0,TotalACW / calls) AS ACW,
    grs.percent AS percent,
    TRUNCATE (((grs_total - wo_ci) / grs_total) *100,2) AS percent_w_ci,
    TRUNCATE (calls / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS call_per_hour,
    TRUNCATE (GRS_total / ( ((TotalLoginTime-TotalEreq-TotalDefault) /3600) / 8.75 ) ,2) AS grs_per_hour 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fullname,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '138',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalAssisting,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '146',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBRB,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '143',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalShift,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '141',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalACW,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '231',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalEreq,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '0',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalDefault,
            COUNT(ReasonCode = '136') AS CountLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '136',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalLunch,
            SUM( IF (ReasonCode =  '137',  `ReasonCodeDuration` , 0) ) AS TotalBreak,
            SUM(  `ReasonCodeDuration` ) AS NRduration
        FROM  `CiscoAgentNotready` 
        WHERE StartDate >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-120)." 00:00:00' 
                AND StartDate <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY fullname)
        AS notready, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT agentname,
            SUM( loginduration ) AS TotalLoginTime, COUNT(Date(logondate)) as DaysLoggedIn
        FROM CiscoAgentLogintime
        WHERE logondate  >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-120)." 00:00:00' 
                AND logondate  <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59'
        GROUP BY agentname)
        AS logintime, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT full_name, 
            SUM( handled ) AS calls
        FROM  `CiscoAgentCalls` 
        WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-120)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."'
        GROUP BY full_name)
        AS calls, 
    (SELECT DISTINCT logging_officer, 
            SUM( first_call ) AS firstcall, 
            SUM(IF (Config_item =  'unknown', 1, 0) ) AS wo_ci,
            COUNT( * ) AS GRS_total, 
            TRUNCATE ((SUM( first_call ) / COUNT( * )) *100,2) AS percent
        FROM (SELECT logging_officer, 
                IF (logging_officer =  `Resolving_Officer` , 1, 0) AS first_call, 
                Config_item
            FROM  `callcentergrsdata` 
            WHERE log_Date >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-120)." 00:00:00' 
                 AND log_Date <= '".$DateTo." 23:59:59') 
            AS a
        GROUP BY logging_officer) 
        AS grs,
    (SELECT DISTINCT agtName,
            SUM(TalkTime) as sumTalk,
            SUM(CallsHandled) as answered,
            SUM(TalkTime)/SUM(CallsHandled) as ACD_Time
        FROM (SELECT CONCAT( LastName,  ', ', FirstName ) AS agtName,
                TalkTime, 
                CallsHandled
            FROM `CiscoAgentAHT`
            WHERE DateCol   >= '".adjustdate($DateTo,0,0,-120)."'  
                AND DateCol   <= '".$DateTo."') as subAHT
        GROUP BY agtName) 
        AS AHT,
    techjtblnew
WHERE mdt_userid = '".$user."'
AND notready.fullname = logintime.agentname
AND calls.full_name = notready.fullname 
AND calls.full_name = AHT.agtName
AND techjtblnew.cisco = notready.fullname 
AND grs.logging_officer = techjtblnew.grs
```

Comment: can i see your queries? can probably be combined to one query. i won't ask why you want to.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you show your queries?

Comment: Two questions. The 3 queries are the same but it only differs the range (30, 90, 180), right? And do you want a row that would appear in the range 180 to appear in the other two ranges or would it be ok just to make it different (for instance, call the range 30 "1", the range 90 "2" and the range 180 "3")? This way you wouldn't repeat data

Comment: Correct, the 3 queries are identical except the timespan and yes, the data in the row for 30 days is also included in the other two rows which is what the managers requested.

Comment: Is this not the ideal scenario for a temp table?  You could do three insert into statements and then select on the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just query for the last 180 days and parse it in the software layer.

If you want an indicator of which one each row is, you can use `CASE` or `IF` statements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, now that I know what you are going for I can provide a better solution that I believe will fit your needs.

I don't think that there is a way out of doing `UNION` **BUT** you if you do the `UNION` ahead of time adding a column for the various time spans you can just query once on the results.

In this example, I create a column called `span` during the `UNION`.  The `t1` is the resulting "table".  Since `span` is different for each date range, the rows will show up multiple times.

Example Table:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------------+
| id | when       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2012-02-01 |
|  2 | 2012-01-01 |
|  3 | 2011-09-01 |
+----+------------+
```

Query With Unions:

```
mysql> 
    ->    SELECT *, 1 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2012-01-15'
    -> UNION
    ->    SELECT *, 2 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2011-12-15'
    -> UNION
    ->    SELECT *, 3 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2011-08-15';

+----+------------+------+
| id | when       | span |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 2012-02-01 |    1 |
|  2 | 2012-01-01 |    2 |
|  1 | 2012-02-01 |    2 |
|  3 | 2011-09-01 |    3 |
|  2 | 2012-01-01 |    3 |
|  1 | 2012-02-01 |    3 |
+----+------------+------+
```

Query Using That Union (custom `SELECT` and `WHERE t1.id > 0`):

```
mysql> 
    -> SELECT
    ->    `id`,
    ->    `when`,
    ->    if(`span` = 1, 'Last 30 Days',
    ->       if(`span` = 2, 'Last 60 Days',
    ->          'Last 180 Days')) as 'Timespan'
    -> FROM (
    ->       SELECT *, 1 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2012-01-15'
    ->    UNION
    ->       SELECT *, 2 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2011-12-15'
    ->    UNION
    ->       SELECT *, 3 as 'span' FROM `test` WHERE `when` > '2011-08-15'
    -> ) as t1
    -> WHERE t1.id > 0;

+----+------------+---------------+
| id | when       | Timespan      |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 2012-02-01 | Last 30 Days  |
|  2 | 2012-01-01 | Last 60 Days  |
|  1 | 2012-02-01 | Last 60 Days  |
|  3 | 2011-09-01 | Last 180 Days |
|  2 | 2012-01-01 | Last 180 Days |
|  1 | 2012-02-01 | Last 180 Days |
+----+------------+---------------+
```

You will do all of your query stuff off of `t1`, not off the table itself. Adding the extra column in the creation of `t1` allows each row to appear multiple times as the extra row will cause it to be unique.

Comment: This looks like what I was originally thinking, but I thought for if and case statements something could only match one time and as I would need the same set of data to be in three different rows I didn't think this would work. Let me know if I am missing something though, cause I would be more than happy if I could get something as simple as a case statement to work for this situation.

Comment: @blade1981m Ok, basically, I think you just want to avoid having to repeat the query multiple times.  Unfortunately, I don't think you can get out of the `UNION`. I think this updated solution will work for you in your situation. Just do the minimal amount of timing stuff in the subquery to give you whatever extra columns you'll need.  You can create any number of addition columns to be used in the super-query.  Originally I had 3 new columns with a 1 or a 0 in them.  Hence using `if()` rather than `case`, but `case` would work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could get away with a complex grouping.  E.g., here's a generic way to do it with records:

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  MIN(creation)
FROM record
WHERE creation > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 120 DAY
GROUP BY 
 IF(creation>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY,'030',
   IF(creation>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY,'090',
     IF(creation>CURDATE() - INTERVAL 120 DAY,'120',
       'OLDER'
     )
   )
 )
```

You would want to add the records as you go, as each range is exclusive.

Here's a sample output:

```
+----------+---------------+
| count(*) | MIN(creation) |
+----------+---------------+
|     1472 | 2012-01-08    |
|     2336 | 2011-11-09    |
|     1528 | 2011-10-10    |
|     5336 | 2011-10-10    |
+----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.13 sec)
```

Comment: Lol, I just noticed that my timespans for the third range were 120, it was supposed to be 180, but anyways - I think your suggestion is a good way to go, but I'm confused as to how this would get me three rows of data with each row including the row before as it looks like from your output you get 3 rows that are exclusive, and then one additional row that totals them all

Comment: Actually, that output is somewhat incorrect.  It's from a different version of the query, with "WITH ROLLUP" added to the group statement.  Usually there would just be three lines.  As for them being exclusive, you would have to add the data you cared about to a running total as you process each row, so it's not a perfect solution.